# Exposing application events from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, ipc

I have a binary application written in c++ that achieves some copying and analysis of data. I can output how much analysis is left i.e. a progress of some sort.

Now I wish to have a web interface to allow me to run this service over the network and monitor its progress. I want to write the web application interface in Java. Is there a way to communicate between the two types of applications i.e. being able to monitor the progress of c++ application from a Java application.

Can [Named Pipes](http://www.cs.fredonia.edu/zubairi/s2k2/csit431/more_pipes.html) achieve such a thing?
Also, will the solution be cross-platform? or is this just plainly impossible.

Comment: Look into SWIG: http://www.swig.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the C++ binary from Java using a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object (either by using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or the quick and dirty method [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29)), you can use [process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) to read the text output of the C++ binary.

Comment: Named pipe does a better job at this than using Input and output streams.

Comment: But named pipes aren't cross-plattform. There is something like named pipes in Windows, but it works very differently from UNIX. The biggest difference is that you can't just redirect any program to a named pipe - the sending program must create a pipe through a WinAPI call. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx